# Get all instances created by Guice Provider

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Assuming a `ClassX` as:

```
class ClassX {
    
    int value;
    
    ClassX() {
        this.value = new Random().nextInt(10);
    }

    //equals and hashCode depend on "value"
}
```

If I have a `Provider` as:

```
@Provides
public ClassX createInstance() {
    return new ClassX();
}
```

Is there a way to inject all the instances created, so I can sum up all values in `total`? I tried something like:

```
@Inject
public Test(Set<ClassX> set) {
    this.set = set
}

int total() {
    return this.set.stream()
            .map(classX -> classX.value)
            .reduce(0, Integer::sum);
}
```

but it fails. Worth mentioning that I read about `MultiBinder` but I would need the instances in order to add them to the `Set`, so, does not seem an option for this case.

Comment: May be an X-Y problem.  What answer do you need to have?

Comment: added more details to question, as you can see, I want to have a `total`

Comment: Why do you want to have a total?

Comment: I use the `total` as a variable to be monitored over time, for example, if `ClassX` is instead `ThreadPoolExecutor`, I would like to know how many threads are running every minute in each pool created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the simple case of just maintaining the list inside of the `Provider` do the trick?  Work in your preferred method of thread safety around `instances`.

```
class MyProvider implements Provider {
   Set<ClassX> instances = new HashSet<>();

   public ClassX get() {
        ClassX classX = new ClassX();
        instances.add(classX);
        return classX;
   }

   public Set<ClassX> getInstances() {
      // ... calculate what you need
   }
}
```

I don't believe there is any way to tell Guice to save all of the instances it's created or provided.